# Can a Schengen Visa be refused because the photograph is too old?

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, visa-refusals

I submitted a Schengen visa application today. The receptionist who accepted my application called me later stating that my photo is more than 6 months old and I need to submit a new photo today. I could not submit it today. She said that she will send the application today to the Swiss embassy and embassy may call me if new photo is required. 
Can they refuse the visa based on this reason?

Comment: Yes, they most likely will refuse the visa... photographs for schengen visa should not be more than 6 months old. it's the same for all schengen states, and not just Switzerland.

Comment: How can they tell?

Comment: @gerrit perhaps the photograph has a date on the back.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the Swiss Ministry of Foreign Affairs requires that photographs attached to visa applications [are not more than 6 months old](https://www.eda.admin.ch/content/dam/countries/countries-content/united-states-of-america/en/Schengen_Photo%20requirements.pdf).

Comment: Same goes for Finland.